# passing a pointer to a struct, to a fuction

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

My C++ skills are amateurish at best, and I need to write some code to interface with a 3rd party sensor by way of a manufacturer provided .dll

As such, the function definitions are provided by the manufacture, but i'm really not sure of the correct way to implement them.

I have two structs, as per the API documentation, defined as per that documentation, but I can't figure out how to pass a pointer of the structs to the required function - HPK_GetSensorInformation(DeviceHandle,
PUNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER IntegParam,
PUNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION SensorInfo
);.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Code attatched:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "CMOS_USB.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    typedef struct _tag_UnitIntegrationParameter {
    unsigned short Xray_Start_Threshold = 10;
    unsigned short Integration_Stop_Threshold = 20;
    double Integration_Time = 100;
    } UNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER, *PUNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER;

    typedef struct _tag_UnitSensorInformation {
        UNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER IntegParam;
        unsigned short XXXX;
        unsigned char YY;
        unsigned char FW;
    } UNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION,*PUNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION;

    unsigned short ProductID = 0x4400;
    HANDLE DeviceHandle;
    HANDLE PipeHandle; 
    unsigned long sensor_return_status;



    DeviceHandle = WINAPI USB_OpenDevice(ProductID);

    PipeHandle = WINAPI USB_OpenPipe(DeviceHandle);

    sensor_return_status =  WINAPI HPK_GetSensorInformation(DeviceHandle,
        PUNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER IntegParam,
        PUNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION SensorInfo
    );

    WINAPI USB_CloseDevice(DeviceHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look to be duplicating the definitions of these structs, not creating one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "CMOS_USB.h"

int main(){

    unsigned short ProductID = 0x4400;
    UNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION SensorInformation;

    HANDLE DeviceHandle = USB_OpenDevice(ProductID);

    // not used?
    HANDLE PipeHandle = USB_OpenPipe(DeviceHandle);

    unsigned long sensor_return_status = HPK_GetSensorInformation(DeviceHandle, &SensorInformation.IntegParam, &SensorInformation);

    USB_CloseDevice(DeviceHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thankyou so much! That compiles. 

How do i go about changing the values in one of the structs? for example, xray start threshold. 

This is more than likely a stupid question, so i thank you for your patience. I'm a python guy...

Comment: @BenBird `SensorInformation.IntegParam.Xray_Start_Threshold = some_value;` A struct is like a python class (although you can't add or remove members at runtime)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for your helo. I was starting to get worried!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with any Windows-specific stuff, but using generic C++:

```
HPK_GetSensorInformation(DeviceHandle, &UNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER, &UNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION );.
```

The `&` says "pass the address of this structure". That is, it passes a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yeah the last time I used windows was when Vista was a thing... But a jobs a job.

That gives the following error -

xray_detector.cpp:46:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
 I HPK_GetSensorInformation(DeviceHandle, &UNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER, &UNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION );
                                                                     ^
xray_detector.cpp:46:102: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 ormation(DeviceHandle, &UNIT_INTEGRATION_PARAMETER, &UNIT_SENSOR_INFORMATION );